# Random effects model: Observations from the same level have covariance $\sigma^2$?

Tags: covariance, random-effects-model

I'm trying to understand what the following means (or how it's displayed):

For a one way random effects model:

$$Y_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ij}$$

$\alpha_i \sim N(0,\sigma_A^2)$, $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, $\alpha_i$s and $\epsilon_{ij}$s independent and $\alpha_i$s independent from $\epsilon_{ij}$s.

Now:

> Observations from the same factor level will have covariance $\sigma_A^2$

from: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/asbio/vignettes/ranef.cov.pdf

But how is this seen? How do I calculate the covariance matrix?

Answer (score 1):

For $j \neq k$ we have

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(Y_{ij}, Y_{ik}) &= \text{Cov}(\mu + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij}, \mu + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ik}) \\
&= \text{Cov}(\alpha_i, \alpha_i) \\
&= \sigma^2_A .
\end{align}

Comment: How does the second equality follow?

Comment: The constants and error terms drop out due to independence.

Comment: I see nothing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance that points to that kind of rule.

Comment: Independence implies zero correlation.  You can prove this yourself by showing $\text{E}(XY) = \text{E}(X) \text{E}(Y)$ for independent $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Can't this be shown along the lines of: $Cov(\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ij},\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ik})=E[(\mu+\alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij}-E(\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ij}))(\mu+ \alpha_i+\epsilon_{ik}-E(\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ik}))]=E[(\mu+\alpha_i+ \epsilon_{ij}-\mu-E(\alpha_i)-E( \epsilon_{ij})))(\mu+\alpha_i+\epsilon_{ik}-\mu-E(\alpha_i)-E(\epsilon_{ik})))]$?

Comment: I wouldn't write out the definition of covariance, just use the linearity property along with independence as above.

Comment: But I don't understand how to interpret $Cov(\mu+ \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ij}, \mu + \alpha_i + \epsilon_{ik})$. I mean where does one apply independence or linearity in that?

Comment: I think I found the covariance linearity: http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Covariance.html

Comment: $\text{Cov}(X + Y, Z) = \text{Cov}(X, Z) + \text{Cov}(Y, Z)$.  Use this property, apply independence and you are done.